# Проблемы с Firebase Unity SDK на живом Android

Tags: c#, unity3d, firebase, unity3d-android, firebase-android

Разрабатываем игру на Unity для Android. Для хранения данных и авторизации используем Firebase, и, соответственно Firebase Unity SDK. Установили все полностью по официальной инструкции (https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup). Имя приложения и хеш сертификата в настройках поставили. В самом редакторе все работает идеально, и БД и авторизация/регистрация. Но когда запускаем на Android (живой телефон, не эмулятор), прямо при запуске возникает такое исключение:

```
DllNotFoundException: FirebaseCppApp-6_15_0  
Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor () (at <685b3a51c27c408fbee657ce47c3e07c>:0)  
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SWIGExceptionHelper' threw an exception.
Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE..cctor () (at <685b3a51c27c408fbee657ce47c3e07c>:0)  
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE' threw an exception.  
Firebase.AppUtil.SetLogFunction (Firebase.LogUtil+LogMessageDelegate arg0) (at <685b3a51c27c408fbee657ce47c3e07c>:0)  
Firebase.LogUtil..ctor () (at <685b3a51c27c408fbee657ce47c3e07c>:0)  
Firebase.LogUtil..cctor () (at <685b3a51c27c408fbee657ce47c3e07c>:0)  
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.LogUtil' threw an exception.  
Firebase.FirebaseApp..cctor () (at <685b3a51c27c408fbee657ce47c3e07c>:0)
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.FirebaseApp' threw an exception.  
Loading.InitFirebase () (at <275f50bb01594ff7972596157b14751b>:0)  
Loading.Start () (at <275f50bb01594ff7972596157b14751b>:0)
```

---

И вот вопрос: что это за исключение и что с ним делать?

Comment: Unity 2019.4.1f, Firebase SDK 6.15.0, компиляция Mono, .Net Framework 4.x

Comment: Универсального ответа я не нашел, НО. У меня эту ошибку исправили следующие действия:  1. В переменные среды вписываем JAVA_HOME (если вы не знаете, как это сделать, погуглите).  2. Убеждаемся, что в проекте у вас есть ExternalDependencyManager  3. Перезагружаете Unity  4. В Project Settings -> Player -> Android -> Other Settings -> Configuration ставим Scripting Backend "IL2CPP", снимаем птичку с ARMv7 и ставим её на ARM64.  5. Готово!